# finding working days in sql

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have a table 'country_holiday' which has two columns country_id and holiday_dt , this table doesnt have entries for weekends.
I need to write a procedure that takes 3 inputs start_dt , end_dt and country_id and then iterate over all working dates between the two given dates for given country_id

I tried writing something like this which doesnt work ( i get a blank cursor)

```
create or replace procedure check_data(p_start_date in date, p_end_date in date, p_country_id in number)
IS
curr_date date;
CURSOR v_buss_days is select p_start_date + rownum -1
from all_objects where rownum <= p_end_date - p_start_date +1
and to_char(p_start_date+rownum-1,'DY') not in ('SAT','SUN')
and p_start_date + rownum -1 not in (select holiday_dt from country_holiday where country_id = p_country_id)

BEGIN
 for curr_date in v_buss_days
LOOP
dbms_output.put_line(curr_date)
END LOOP;
END
```

I tried running the query

```
select p_start_date + rownum -1
from all_objects where rownum <= p_end_date - p_start_date +1
and to_char(p_start_date+rownum-1,'DY') not in ('SAT','SUN')
```

this gives me 0 rows with p_start_date='01 dec 2013' and p_end_date='31 dec 2013' , seems like my query to populate cursor is incorrect.

After populating the cursor correctly i face issue

thanks for your help , indeed it works .... but facing issue when i try to use in procedure ....

```
create or replace procedure check_data(p_start_date in date, p_end_date in date, p_cntry_id in number)
IS
curr_num_of_empoyee number;
curr_date date;
CURSOR v_buss_days is select work_date from
( with dates  as 
   ( select p_start_date dt_start, p_end_date dt_end    from dual  )
  select dt_start + (level-1) work_date from dates
  connect by level <= (dt_end - dt_start + 1 )
  ) wdates
where work_date not in ( select HOLIDAY_DATE 
                        from country_holiday
                        where country_id = p_cntry_id)
and to_char(work_date,'DY') not in ('SAT','SUN')
order by work_date;
BEGIN
for curr_date in v_buss_days
LOOP
select count(*)  into curr_num_of_empoyee from employee_details where country_id = p_cntry_id and data_dt = curr_date;
END LOOP;
END;
```

Error is 
19/101         PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type

seems like issue is in part "data_dt = curr_date"

Comment: What about it doesn't work?

Comment: What do you mean by 'iterate'?  You want to print out all the work days that are not holidays or weekend?

Comment: OldProgrammer you are right , GolezTrol updated details in question

Comment: The SELECT statements in both your procedure and standalone query are reading from `ALL_OBJECTS` instead of your `COUNTRY_HOLIDAY` table. I wouldn't expect either one to compile or run. Try changing the table name to see if that helps.

Comment: @Lav: try clause `data_dt = curr_date.work_date` in the last SELECT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a query I put on [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b30115/27).   Remove the WITH clause and replace with your procedure date parameters.  You can use the combination of CONNECT BY and LEVEL to generate a set of rows with increasing numeric values.  Then, add that to your start date, and filter out from your holiday table and weekends.

```
select work_date from
(
   with dates  as 
   ( select to_date('01/01/2014','MM/DD/YYYY') dt_start,
     to_date('01/10/2014','MM/DD/YYYY') dt_end
     from dual
   )
  select dt_start + (level-1) work_date
  from dates
  connect by level <= (dt_end - dt_start + 1 )
  ) wdates
where work_date not in ( select holiday_dt 
                        from country_holiday
                        where country_id = 1)
and to_char(work_date,'DY') not in ('SAT','SUN')
order by work_date
```

Comment: thanks for your help , indeed it works .... but facing issue when i try to use in procedure .... posted in ques , will appreciate your help on that